# How do I get Automator to process images using ImageMagick in a command script?

Tags: macos, automator, bash, script

I'm making an Automator workflow that uses the shell script action to process a selection of images with the imagemagick composite command. Only I'm having issues getting it going. According to the results I get when I run the workflow, everything is working however, I know it's not due to the fact that the changes I'd expect to see in the folder of images are not present. I know that the imagemagick command I'm using is correct as it works correctly from the console. (I echoed the composite command to the output & copied it into a Terminal session. Ran like a charm). BTW: The workflow's for processing a fade in on a stop motion movie I made. Yes I know I could use video tools to achieve the same thing, but the ones I have access to screw up the image quality on output.

Here's the script

```
imagesCount=$#
rate=$(echo "scale=2; 100/$imagesCount"|bc)
percentage=$rate
for f in "$@"; do
    fileName=${f%.*}
    composite -blend "$percentage" -size 1280x720 "$f" xc:black -alpha Set "$fileName-1.jpg"
    percentage=$(echo "scale=2; $percentage+$rate"|bc)
done
```

At first I thought at the cause of the problem might be spaces in the paths, but I removed this possibility by shifting the files to a path without spaces, but that had no effect.

I'm almost certain the issue is related to something in the bash command but I don't know bash at all, this is my first time writing any bash command scripts, but I am very knowledgeable in Windows console scripting and would have no trouble getting this to work there.

If the error in the script isn't obvious enough to catch, would someone propose a method to debug this so I can figure out why the images are not getting processed even though the script runs without error?

Comment: Maybe it's a PATH issue. Does it work when you replace `composite` with its absolute path (can be determined by executing `which composite` on the Terminal)?

Comment: The following line of code seems to be missing a quotation mark:     percentage=$(scale=2; $percentage+$rate"|bc)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Kaydell. It was also missing its echo.

Comment: Composite's installed correctly.  i used Cactus Labs ImageMagick installer which installs ImageMagick and adds it to the path. Very handy.

Comment: Did it work to change `$f` to `f` or was that just a transcription error? Also your capitalization on `fileName` is inconsistent.

Comment: Transcription errors, both.

Comment: OK. I made the script above into a shell script. Named it fader.command gave it executable permission and ran it as ./fader.command IMG*.jpg. Works like a charm. So why doesn't it work in Automator? Anyone have any ideas? I'd like to get it to work in Automator as that‘s an easy route to user-friendly path selection. Rather annoying that it doesn‘t “just work”.

As an aside I also tried adding #!/bin/bash to the Automator script. Had no effect. Bummed.

Answer (score 2):

I would just do the whole thing at the command line as a shell script instead of using Automator to launch it. Put `#!/bin/bash` as the first line, and run it as

`myscript.sh image*.png`

where `image*.png` is your set of image files that you are apparently selecting in Automator?

If you need to run it on all files in a folder, that can be done too.

You can also test your script in automator using `echo ${f%.*}` instead of the commands themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `for $f` with `for f`. `for $f in aa; do :; done` results in an error like `` `$f': not a valid identifier ``.

Also if `composite` is not on the path, specify the full path to it (like `/usr/local/bin/composite`).